What is wrong with this C code to control a LED using a sensor and a push button?
I am trying to program an ATmega328P to control an LED using an HC-SR04 sensor and a push button. My goal is for the sensor to turn ON the LED (like turn on a light in a room) when something passes within a 10 cm distance and to use the button to toggle the LED's state (turn it ON and OFF), but it doesn’t work.
The code seems correct to me, but when I test it, it doesn’t work as expected. The LED turns ON with the sensor, and when I press the button, it turns OFF, but after that, nothing else happens. Both the sensor and the button stop working, and I can’t understand why. Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this and what I need to change?
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define LED_PIN PD2
#define BUTTON_PIN PD3
#define TRIGGER_PIN PD5
#define ECHO_PIN PD6

void toggle_led() {
    PORTD ^= (1 << LED_PIN);
}

void turn_on_led() {
    if (!(PORTD & (1 << LED_PIN))) {
        PORTD |= (1 << LED_PIN);
    }
}

uint16_t measure_distance() {
    uint16_t duration = 0;
    PORTD |= (1 << TRIGGER_PIN);
    _delay_us(10);
    PORTD &= ~(1 << TRIGGER_PIN);

    while (!(PIND & (1 << ECHO_PIN)));
    while (PIND & (1 << ECHO_PIN)) {
        duration++;
        _delay_us(1);
    }

    uint16_t distance = (duration / 58);
    return distance;
}

int main(void) {
    DDRD |= (1 << LED_PIN);
    DDRD &= ~(1 << BUTTON_PIN);
    DDRD |= (1 << TRIGGER_PIN);
    DDRD &= ~(1 << ECHO_PIN);

    uint8_t button_pressed = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (!(PIND & (1 << BUTTON_PIN))) {
            if (!button_pressed) {
                toggle_led();
                button_pressed = 1;
            }
        } else {
            button_pressed = 0;
        }

        uint16_t distance = measure_distance();
        if (distance <= 10) {
            turn_on_led();
        }

        _delay_ms(100);
    }

    return 0;
}


Try to Add Delay: After detecting a button press, a short delay _delay_ms(100)  helps prevent unintended multiple toggles due to button bounce.

Your measure_distance function has two loops in it that could potentially run forever, causing everything else in your program to break.

You have no button debouncing so that's why. You need to implement that before anything else. For example having a timer cyclically scanning the buttons every 10ms and comparing against the previous read. You can't have some 100ms busy-delay, because the user is not so kind as to press the button on those microseconds between your massive delays.

@Dilux No, that is not how you debounce a button...

Following on to @4386427 's answer,  I'd recommend to clearly specify the expected results when the proximity distance is met (and add it to post) and when it is cleared.   This can be summarized as whether (A) the LED indicates "the proximity has been breached (a single instance in time)" OR (B) the LED indicates "something is currently within proximity" or (C) something else you specify.  (A) and (B) would require different solutions for the button handling.

Here is one potential problem:
Let's assume that measure_distance always returns a value <= 10. Either because the sensor correctly measured that distance or because of some problem with the sensor.
With measure_distance always returning a value <= 10, your main loop can be rewritten as:
while (1) {
    if (!(PIND & (1 << BUTTON_PIN))) {
        if (!button_pressed) {
            toggle_led();
            button_pressed = 1;
        }
    } else {
        button_pressed = 0;
    }

    turn_on_led();  // When measure_distance always returns <= 10

    _delay_ms(100);
}

So even when your button press turns the LED off, you will turn the LED back on instantly. Your eyes/brain won't notice any change - it's happening too fast.
You need to add a "big" delay after the button press. Perhaps start like:
            toggle_led();
            _delay_ms(1000);

I would also recommend that you test the sensor "stand-alone". Something like:
while (1) {
    uint16_t distance = measure_distance();
    if (distance <= 10) {
        toggle_led();     // NOTICE TOGGLE
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}

When an object is sufficiently close, the LED should toggle every second. Otherwise the LED should keep its state.
